# State is set but firebase doesnt register first click

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, state

I'm trying to both set the state of my app and update the firebase realtime database with one function. When the app is loaded, the first click updates the state, but does not log to firebase. On the second click (and beyond), the state is toggled and the firebase db is updated, but with the opposite boolean value that is expected.

I've tried using different configurations of functions to handle this, but nothing is working! Always the same result

```
onGoalPressOne = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    goalOne: {
      goal: prevState.goalOne.goal,
      completed: !prevState.goalOne.completed,
    }
  }));
  let now = moment(new Date()).format('YYYYMMDD')
  let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
  console.log(userId)

  function writeUserData(userId, goalOne1, goalTwo2, goalThree3) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId + '/' + now).set({
      goalOne: goalOne1,
      goalTwo: goalTwo2,
      goalThree: goalThree3
    });
  }

  writeUserData(userId, this.state.goalOne, this.state.goalTwo, this.state.goalThree)
  // console.log('hello')
}
```

The expected outcome is to have the database and state updated on click with the same value (not have the database lagged by one boolean toggle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the firebase logic inside the callback of `setState`

```
onGoalPressOne = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    goalOne: {
      goal: prevState.goalOne.goal,
      completed: !prevState.goalOne.completed,
    }
  }), () => {
    let now = moment(new Date()).format('YYYYMMDD')
    let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    console.log(userId)

    function writeUserData(userId, goalOne1, goalTwo2, goalThree3) {
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId + '/' + now).set({
        goalOne: goalOne1,
        goalTwo: goalTwo2,
        goalThree: goalThree3
      });
    }

    writeUserData(userId, this.state.goalOne, this.state.goalTwo, this.state.goalThree)
    // console.log('hello')
  });
}
```